# count matched objects within another objects

Tags: javascript, oop, object

let me elaborate the issue:

i want to define a parent objects for example usedCars. then inside usedCars i want to add some cars. for sure i want to be able to count the number of matched usedCars based on milage.

here is what i am using, but because i am newbie, i can't go forward!

```
    var usedCar = {
        //constructor for cars
        car: function(model, year, miles){ 
            this.model = model;
            this.year  = year;
            this.miles = miles;
        },
        //some objects
    }
```

so if I instantiate a new usedCar i should do following?

```
    var shelby = new usedCar.car('Shelby', 1990, 7500); 
    // i have no idea is this working or not!
```

so , if everything working well i want to count number of matched usedCar

```
    usedCar.prototype.findIt = function(maxMilage){
        //should i use for in or something like that here?
        // i want to search through many available used cars and 
        // count based on maxMilage arg.
    }
```

could someone help me? i know i am lame in both JS and English, haha.
if I am wrong, please give me some suggestion for how to implement such a scenario.

thank you all.

Comment: First part: yes, this will work. It's pretty easy to paste code in console and get shelby.year > 1990; I didn't understand Second part. Where you'll do search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var usedCar = {
    carList: [],
    findIt: function(maxMileage) {
        var result = [];
        for(var i=0;i<usedCar.carList.length;i++){
            if(usedCar.carList[i].miles < maxMileage) {
               result.push(usedCar.carList[i]);   
            }
        }
        return result;
    },
    //constructor for cars
    car: function(model, year, miles){ 
        this.model = model;
        this.year  = year;
        this.miles = miles;
        usedCar.carList.push(this);
    },
    //some objects
}
var shelby = new usedCar.car('Shelby', 1990, 7500);  
var searchResults = usedCar.findIt(10000);  
console.log(searchResults.length);   // Number of matching cars
```

Comment: thank you, now i understand that how could i implement my idea. i should use arrays to store data, not simple object.

Answer (score 0):

wrote it in notepad but this should work..

```
function maxMilage(number) {
int counter =  0;
for (var i=0;i<usedCar.carList.length;i++)
{ 
    if(usedCar[i].miles < number)
    { counter++; }
}
console.log(counter);
}
```

Comment: His code doesn't define carList so this will not work.  I guess you took it from my example.  Also, there is no `miles` property on usedCar.